# DB2 ODBC Connection String without Database Name

Tags: db2, odbc

I am trying to connect DB2 Server with ODBC, which is working fine if I specify `Database` in connection string.

```
driver   = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER'
server   = '10.30.30.114'
port     = '50000'
protocol = 'TCPIP'
database = 'SAMPLE'

user = 'administrator'
pass = 'password'

DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:Driver=#{driver};HostName=#{server};Port=#{port};Protocol=#{protocol};Database=#{database};Uid=#{user};Pwd=#{pass};")
```

The issue is I will not be knowing the database name in advance at the time of connecting to the server. I want the list of databases on the server and then tables in those databases, how should I approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "connect to a DB2 server" via ODBC; you can only connect to a database, for which you obviously need to specify the database name. You could use the DB2 C/C++ API calls `db2DbDirOpenScan` and `db2DbDirGetNextEntry` to list the database directory, but this code will need to be executed on the server itself, otherwise it will attempt to list the database catalog on the client machine.

Comment: This is a platform specific answer for DB2 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are connecting to **DB2 for i** server (formerly DB2 UDB on OS/400) --

Initially connect using hostname, allowing database to default. You can then get a list of databases in the DB2 for i [SYSCATALOGS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcatsyscatalog.htm) view.  Your query might look like this:

```
SELECT catalog_name,        -- database name
       catalog_text         -- DB description
FROM QSYS2.SYSCATALOGS
WHERE catalog_type='LOCAL'  -- local to that host
  AND catalog_status='AVAILABLE'  -- REMOTE catalogs are 'UNKNOWN' status
```

You could then connect to that database if .  Once connected to the appropriate database, you could query other [DB2 for i catalog views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcatalogtbls.htm) such as [SYSSCHEMAS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcatsysschemas.htm) and [SYSTABLES](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcatsysschemas.htm).  [ODBC/JDBC Catalog views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcatalogodbc.htm) and [ANS/ISO Catalog views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcatalogans.htm) would also be available.

[Other API's](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikapiinterfaces.htm) are available outside of an ODBC connection via IBM i Access, if you prefer.